# How to change the position of docky notifications?

Tags: gnome, notification, docky

I'm using docky in Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell and sometimes the notifications cover the dock. It would be great if the position of the notifications can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [tweaking tool](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html) just for this purpose. However, it seems to involve installing a different version of `notify-osd`. This is from the link above:

> Install the patched (configurable) NotifyOSD in Ubuntu 11.10 or 11.04:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik 
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
> pkill notify-osd
> ```
>
> Install NotifyOSD Config:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
> ```