# Notification out of screen

Tags: notification

How to solve the problem? The notifications extrude the screen.Anyone could help?

[image: notifications extrude the screen]

Comment: does anything in this answer help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/69047/how-to-change-the-position-of-notifications-on-gnome-shell

Comment: they seem to be different notifify-osds, mine is gnome3's, your link is unity notify-osd. I thought this could be a bug, but I do not know where to report. There is no application called notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Tutorial that shows how to adjust the position of Notify [Tweaking Notify-OSD, incl. GUI for Placement, all Ubuntus](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/06/tweaking-notify-osd.html) The default version of Notify-OSD still doesn't support any kind of configuration. So, this is an update on the available PPAs and the new features added to the patched versions of it. I will also show how to configure it, and introduce here a GUI to change its position I wrote earlier.